# Python eggs are not imported for Apache2 mod_wsgi

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi

I'm setting up Apache2 and mod_wsgi for Django in Debian, but I found problems.
First, these are my directories:

```
/webapps/lib/python2.6/site-packages # python eggs
/webapps/lib/python2.6/ # python libraries
/webapps/myproject.wsgi # wsgi script
/webapps/myproject/ # django project
```

And this is the directory `/webapps/lib/python2.6` (permissions are 777):

```
.
├── django
│   ├── bin
│   ├── conf
│   ├── ...
│   └── views
└── site-packages
    ├── easy-install.pth
    ├── mongoengine-0.5.3-py2.6.egg
    ├── pymongo-2.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg
    └── site.py
```

In `httpd.conf` I have this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /webapps/myproject.wsgi
WSGIPythonEggs /webapps/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

And finally in `myproject.wsgi`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/webapps/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, '/webapps/lib/python2.6')
sys.path.insert(0, '/webapps/myproject')

.. Nothing important

# I tried 2 lines above as well, but nothing
#import os
#os.environ["PYTHON_EGG_CACHE"] = "/webapps/lib/python2.6/site-packages"

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()

# This for trying if system reads eggs
try:
    import mongoengine
except Exception as e:
    raise ImportError(str(e) + ". " + str(sys.path))
```

When I restart Apache and try to visit any webpage, I get error 500 and this in the log:

[Wed Jan 04 18:18:12 2012] [error] [client 217.217.164.22] ImportError: No module named mongoengine. ['/webapps/myproject', '/webapps/lib/python2.6', '/webapps/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6']

So as you can see django is imported well, but none of the eggs are imported. However I didn't find any other way to import them. Why eggs are not imported?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the `mongoengine` module located?

Comment: `mongoengine` is located in `site-packages`, as you can see in the file diagram.

Comment: Ah, missed that.  Have you tried extracting the eggs and see if the package directories themselves will load?

Comment: Yes. By the way, I just found the solution.. after 3 hours :\ Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, nice - glad you got it fixed!

Comment: You should NOT be setting the Python egg cache directory to your site-packages directory, you risk screwing up things by doing that. It should be set to a distinct directory.

Comment: Thanks Graham, I didn't know that. Anyways I commented that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution. Everything was perfect, and even though I was restarting Apache it was throwing all the time the same error. As there are many processes of Apache running, the key was doing a `killall httpd` and then starting the service again. Some kind of cache or process was alive with wrong data so it wasn't working properly.